# Replacing Powerpoint data from Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have some "tables" in excel that I export to a powerpoint every week (I say "tables" because they are actually just ranges of cells and not actually tables). Right now I have a macro that deletes all of the shapes from the powerpoint each week, and then a different macro to export the tables to the powerpoint. The issue with this is that it deletes everything from the powerpoint, including the titles and comments on the slides. So now I am trying to write code that just replaces the previous weeks tables. So far this is the code I have, however it does not work when I get to

```
pptpress.Slides(1).Shapes("Picture 8").Table.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange = Sheet2.Cells(r, c).Value
```

I assume it doesn't work because the range of cells are not actually tables? Anyways, does anyone have any advice on how to replace previous weeks data? I'm struggling over here

```vb
Sub UpdateTables()

    Dim pptapp As New PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptpress As PowerPoint.Presentation
    
    Dim left As Double
    Dim top As Double
    Dim height As Double
    Dim width As Double
    
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    
    Set pptpress = pptapp.Presentations.Open("xxxxxx")

    'Table update
    For r = 4 To 30
    
     For c = 2 To 12
     
        pptpress.Slides(1).Shapes("Picture 8").Table.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange = Sheet2.Cells(r, c).Value
        
    Next c
   Next r


End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?  Do you get an error?  If Yes, what is the error and on which line?

Comment: Try `pptpress.Slides(1).Shapes("Picture 8").Table.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text` (you are missing the last `.Text` part)

Comment: it gives me an error saying "method 'table' of object 'shape' failed". is that because it is just a range of cells that I input the data in and not an actual table?

Comment: Sorry I missed that part about not being actual tables.  If that's the case then you'd need to address each shape individually using some kind on naming pattern which tells you where each one is.  Might be easier just to use a table...

Comment: Is building it from scratch not an option? I do this a bit and editing an existing PPT was always giving me drama so I build it from scratch with code every time.

Answer (score 0):

> > I assume it doesn't work because the range of cells are not actually tables?

Yes. The fact that the shape's name is "Picture 8" is a give-away also. In all likelihood, it's an EMF/WMF/etc picture that's been pasted into the PPT slide.

As @Dan suggests, it might be simplest to insert a new Table shape and work with it. Or if you have a particular table format you need to preserve, add a table manually to the slide, format it, then have your code put the data into it instead.

Answer (score 0):

In order to replace old shapes (or in your case: tables), you could use a marker or a timestamp to identify what needs to be deleted.
A great way for this are **tags** within PowerPoint. You can attach these to presentations, slides and shapes (maybe even more). They are invisible to the user but can be read / written via code (e.g. VBA).

This is what you need to look for:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb//office/vba/api/powerpoint.tags